# Package containerd.io is not available when installing Docker on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I'm currently trying to install Docker on Ubuntu 19.10. I've been following install guide from Docker's [website](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository). When I run the actual install step, I get the following results:

```
$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package containerd.io is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
```

I've tried going through the install guide multiple times to ensure I haven't messed any steps up. I'm not sure what else to try. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You're sure you set up the repository properly in step 4 of that guide? Those 4 lines are one single command that needs to be run, and you must run `apt-get update` after you do it.

Comment: Yes, I copied each command from the guide directly into my terminal. I completed steps 1 through 4 of "Set up the repository", then step 1 of "Install Docker Engine - Community" before the error on step 2.

Comment: Give me remote access to your machine and I'll sort it. The Stack Exchange format doesn't suit resolution of these kind of issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced similar issue. Issue seems to be with the repository we build using the documentation. I replaced "$(lsb_release -cs)" in add repository command with bionic. It worked.

**Instruction in Docker documentation:**

$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"

**Modified command:**

$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu 
 bionic stable"

**Then try to install docker with below command**

$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

Comment: It worked! Thanks for you help. I ran into a weird issue on the install command where docker.service didn't want to start for some reason. Restarting my PC fixed the issue.

Comment: You are welcome:-)